# write logs with CloudWatch : getNextToken error

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I developed the following code to write logs to cloudwtach :

```
import com.greenflex.sag.logs.CloudWatchUtils.checkErrorCode
import software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.CloudWatchLogsClient
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.model.{DescribeLogStreamsRequest, InputLogEvent, PutLogEventsRequest, ResourceNotFoundException}

import java.util

trait CloudWatchLogWriter {
  lazy val logsClient: CloudWatchLogsClient = CloudWatchLogsClient.builder().httpClient(ApacheHttpClient.builder().build())
    .build()
  private val DB_CLUSTER_ID: String = "DB_CLUSTER_ID" //scalastyle:ignore

  def putLog(log: String, logGroupName: String): Unit = {
    val inputLogEvent = InputLogEvent.builder()
      .message(log)
      .timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
      .build()

    val putLogEventsRequest = PutLogEventsRequest.builder()
      .logEvents(util.Arrays.asList(inputLogEvent))
      .logGroupName(logGroupName)
      .logStreamName(sys.env(DB_CLUSTER_ID))
    val sequenceToken = getNextSequenceToken(logsClient, logGroupName, sys.env(DB_CLUSTER_ID))
    val result = putLogEventsRequest.sequenceToken(sequenceToken).build()
    try {
      logsClient.putLogEvents(result)
    }
    catch {
      case e: ResourceNotFoundException =>
        if (checkErrorCode(e.statusCode()) || e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage().contains("log stream")) {
          CloudWatchUtils.createLogStream(logsClient, logGroupName, sys.env(DB_CLUSTER_ID))
          logsClient.putLogEvents(result)
        }
    }
  }

  private def getNextSequenceToken(logsClient: CloudWatchLogsClient, logGroupName: String, logStreamName: String): String = {
    val logStreamRequest = DescribeLogStreamsRequest.builder.logGroupName(logGroupName).logStreamNamePrefix(logStreamName).build
    val describeLogStreamsResponse = logsClient.describeLogStreams(logStreamRequest)
      describeLogStreamsResponse.logStreams().get(0).uploadSequenceToken()
  }
}
```

And I am getting the following error :

```
ERROR Uncaught throwable from user code: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1311)
ERROR Uncaught throwable from user code: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1311)
at 

com.company.sag.logs.CloudWatchLogWriter$class.getNextSequenceToken(CloudWatchLogWriter.scala:42)
    at com.company.sag.logs.CloudWatchLogWriter$class.putLog(CloudWatchLogWriter.scala:25)
    at com.company.sag.jobs.IngestionJob.putLog(IngestionJob.scala:19)
```

It is about the getNextToken any idea how to fix this please, I followed few examples in github but it wasn't helpful

It is about the getNextToken any idea how to fix this please, I followed few examples in github but it wasn't helpful

Comment: Can you share more of the stack trace error? Like what line of your code resolves in the error?

Comment: @mfirry I did it

Answer (score 1):

The exception is happening because `describeLogStreamsResponse.logStreams()` is empty.

The reason that it's empty is that log group/stream creation is an eventually consistent operation: it may be several seconds before the group/stream is actually ready for use. This is, unfortunately, not covered by the documentation.

The solution is to call `DescribeLogGroups` after creating a group, and `DescribeLogStreams` after creating a stream, looping until they return a result. You should sleep for 100-200 milliseconds between calls.

You should also be prepared for throttling or other retryable conditions: catch [AmazonClientException](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException.html) (assuming you're using the 1.11.x SDK) and check `isRetryable()`. These can be safely ignored inside your loop.